# Is there a way to view a fragment inside of another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need activity details, which are seen in one fragment called `ActivityCard`, to be seen from inside of another fragment called `Timesheet`. The idea is for people that are using the app that I am developing to see activity deatiles that they have typed into the `ActivityCard` fragment of the app to see what they have done in a format inside of the `Timesheet` fragment. I have never done anything like this before in Android Studio, so any help would be appreciated.

`fragment_activity_card.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.ActivityCard">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_card_title"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Debugging App"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.086"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bug"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startEndTimes"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="13:00 -> 14:00"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityDate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="1h 0m"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityDate"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Mon 23 May 2023"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_card_title" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

`fragment_timesheet.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="Activity" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="88dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Date of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="End of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="Activity" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="88dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Date of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="End of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="Activity" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_width="88dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="End of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView25"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you can do that by calling the "parentFragmentManager" from your fragment instead of the "supportFragmentManager" that you use from your activity.

Comment: Neither fragment has those. Who would have the "parentFragmentManager" in this case?

Comment: "supportFragmentManager" is part of the abstract class 'AppCompatActivity()' and "parentFragmentManager" is part of the abstract class 'Fragment()'

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add fragment inside fragment and view it in Android you need to use getChildFragmentManager to add fragment inside at interface to communicate among fragment for data.

This is how it look in ParentFragment onViewCreated fragment

```
 Fragment childernFragment = new ChildernFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment_container, childernFragment).commit();
```

[Fragment Manager](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#access)
[Child Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getChildFragmentManager())